# Choose which pages appear in Google search results snippet?

Tags: google-search

I was wondering sometimes, the first result in Google's results has a list of pages (in the website) below the title of the search result.

Is this something I can force Google to do, with some sort of HTML tags?

Or does Google just do it automatically, when it feels like it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may refer to sitelinks. They are automatically generated by Google.

> We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to
>   the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our algorithms
>   to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks for your
>   site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them.
>
> At the moment, sitelinks are automated. We're always working to
>   improve our sitelinks algorithms, and we may incorporate webmaster
>   input in the future. There are best practices you can follow, however,
>   to improve the quality of your sitelinks. For example, for your site's
>   internal links, make sure you use anchor text and alt text that's
>   informative, compact, and avoids repetition.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en